# WordPress Importer plugin show error message when I import sample data

Tags: php, wordpress

I use WordPress source code version 4.5.3, I install `WordPress Importer` plugin to import sample data from URL `https://wpcom-themes.svn.automattic.com/demo/theme-unit-test-data.xml`

But when I finished importing I received more error message below:

> Deprecated:  Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; WP_Import has a deprecated constructor in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php on line 38`
>
> Warning: Declaration of WP_Import::bump_request_timeout() should be compatible with WP_Importer::bump_request_timeout($val) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php on line 38`
>
> Notice: wp_get_http is deprecated since version 4.4! Use WP_Http instead. in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\functions.php on line 3658`
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php on line 798`
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _menu_item_type in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php on line 800`
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _menu_item_type in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php on line 802`
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: _menu_item_type in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\plugins\wordpress-importer\wordpress-importer.php on line 804`
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\class-wp-http-curl.php on line 239`

Comment: WordPress Importer plugin is not compatible with recent version of WordPress.